# I want to show permission dialog like Google Hangout app while my app is launching

Tags: android, permissions

[image: I want to display this type of permission dialog in my android app.can anyone please share code for this]

I want to display this type of permission dialog in my android app.can anyone please share code for this

Comment: ref this http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: which versions did supporty your app ?

Comment: i develop app for all version..but  its crashing in marshmallow because of run time permission.i want to display this type of permission dialog.

Answer (score 0):

> **Declaring a permission:**
>
> The first step is to declare the permissions of the application in the
>   manifestas we usually do. We'll take the example of access to the
>   contact.
>
> ```
> <uses-permission-sdk-m android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
> <uses-permission-sdk-m android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
> ```
>
> **Check permission**
>
> I present the methods to be used generally
>
> the method `"checkSelfPermission"` allows checking the access
>   authorization to functionality that requires permission and this each
>   time we need to use it.
>
> ```
> int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
>
> Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR);
> ```
>
> `"ContextCompat"` lets you use the context independently of the
>   version of Android. The result of the invocation of this method is
>   either an authorization (Granted) or refusal (Denied).
>
> - The `"shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale"` method is used to    validate if permission has was already checked by the user to avoid
>     checking the authorization again.
> - The `"requestPermissions"` method is used to ask permission to the    user waiting for confirmation.

I hope that support your question.

Source: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1070139/Manage-App-Permissions-on-Android-Marshmallow

Comment: DeJaVo  i wants to display dialog like Google Hangout app.Can you see, in the dialog there are two permissions in queue.It showing like 1/2..

Comment: it will pop the same dialog.  have a look in the source link , see the screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ask multiple permission at runtime just pass multiple permissions array while calling requestPermission(). Here is an example of requesting permission for read storage and read contacts. This will create only single dialog and ask for READ_CONTACTS and READ_STORAGE subsequently.

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.READ_STORAGE},
            MY_MULTIPLE_PERMISSION);
```